# Using variables within a cursor statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to calculate the total time from when a ticket hits the system (daystart) to when it has been resolved (dayend). I do not want to include outside of business hours (8:00 - 18:00).

I have the following columns: App_ID, DayStart, DayEnd, InMin (Solving for).

I have a cursor statement that selects App_ID, DayStart, DayEnd and solves for InMin for weekday tickets. (Tickets that are resolved on same day and tickets that are resolved throughout the week not including weekends)

I did so with an IF statement:

```
IF daystart != dayend then
UPDATE table
set InMin = round ((((dayend)-(daystart))*24)*60),3) - (840 * (dayend)-(daystart)))
```

Works great until I have an app that hits on Friday at 14:00 and isn't resolved until Monday 9:00.

I have thought about creating a variable for day of week:

```
to_char(dayend, 'D') and to_char (daystart, 'D')
```

then do an IF statement:

```
IF daystart < 7 and dayend > 1 then....
```

Not sure on logic.